# How to highlight each unique string value differently in a single column in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, styling

I have a dataframe in Pandas and I want to make it a bit more readable to the user. There many columns/rows and a mix of string and floats.

I have a column, let's call it 'Type', which has about 5 unique possible values let's say 'Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Legume', 'Liquid', 'Meat'.

I want 'Fruit' to ALWAYS be highlighted in, let's say 'yellow'. 'Vegetable' should always have a background-color of 'green', etc.

**How do I generate this styling in Pandas?**

[image]

I'm running into a lot of issues as this isn't a typical use case for this (most of the styling assumes integers/floats are being highlighted).

I've tried using applymap but can't seem to figure out how to get it to highlight a string and only in a single column.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [styling system](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html):

```
def styler(col):
    # We only want to apply style to the Type column
    if col.name != 'Type':
        return [''] * len(col)

    bg_color = col.map({
        'Fruit': 'yellow',
        'Vegetable': 'green',
        'Liquid': 'rgb(0,0,255)',
    }).fillna('') # a fallback for fruits we haven't colorized
    return 'background-color:' + bg_color

df.style.apply(styler)
```

The color values use [CSS Colors specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color)